# Error in SQL (SELECT and LEFT Join) How give id first table?

Tags: sql, select, left-join

I have sql select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `fclients` AS F 
LEFT JOIN `fclients_sequens` AS FS ON F.category = FS.category 
ORDER by FS.num
```

AND I get results:

[image: result select sql]

Then, for given `id` in first table, I make sql query:

```
SELECT *, fclients.id as fclientsID 
FROM `fclients` AS F 
LEFT JOIN `fclients_sequens` AS FS ON F.category = FS.category 
ORDER by FS.num
```

and I get an error:

> *#1054 - Unknown column 'fclients.id' in 'field list'*

Tell me please how give id fist column (id=37)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the alias F when you reference the column ID

```
SELECT *, F.id...
```